# Rails, Devise, Show username in profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using Rails 4 with Devise and created a profile page where I want to show the id and username of that specific user. But as soon as I want to access the users data I get the error:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

My users_controller.rb:

```
def  profile
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

My View

```
<%= @user.id %>
```

Routes

```
get ':username' => 'users#profile'
```

What's wrong?

Any help's appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `@user` is nil.  Thus, `User.find_by_username(params[:username])` is failing to find a record.  You might want to open up rails console and tool around with why it might be failing.

Comment: @Owlet, it's never too late to accept the answer to this question...

Answer (score 4):

Devise creates a method, `current_user` that you can reference within controller and view contexts -- it has all the methods of your `User` model.  So, just do

`current_user.username`

or

`<%= current_user.id %>`

No route needed, no finder needed -- all built in to Devise for you.

Comment: Sadly that's not what I'm looking for, I don't want to display the current_user, I want to display the id of the user the profile is of.

Comment: Aha -- should be easy.  Edited answer on its way.

Comment: Um, so then I am confused. Is a "profile" the information directly associated with a user (for example the user's name) or is Profile _related to_ the User but really a separate thing?  Either is reasonable depending on your data.  If the User record (model) contains all the attributes needed to display your profile page, then I believe my answer is correct, or close.  I have reread your question several times and need more information.  Please edit your question with sufficient detail and I'll take another try.

Answer (score 0):

If you've set up a route for /:username, (as in http://example.com/username) to show a user profile, then you will need to modify the way you are getting your profile in the controller.

```
def action
  @user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
end
```

And with that, in your view you should be able to access on aspects of that user.

```
@user.username -> username
@user.id -> id of @user
```

The reason you received `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` is because your action was not able to find a user for the specified username parameter, so to try and track this issue down, make use of `rails console` to interact with your database and try to find the same user your code is trying to find when it receives the parameter from the route.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. I was troubleshooting a similar problem and tried all of the above, and I didn't have any luck. I thought I'd add this in here in case someone else runs into the same or similar issue.

Localhost - There are two ways to view a users profile depending on how your database is structured.

1) localhost:3000/usersname

2) localhost:3000/users/1 (or localhost:3000/users/usersname) --> This uses "user_id".

In "Views", Show.html.erb file:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```